# Stop time automatically in Javascript using clearTimeout()

Tags: javascript, timer, stopwatch

I am creating the Pong Game using WebGL, but what I trying to do is that when the ball touches the wall I want my stopwatch to stop automatically. Here is my code of timer:

```
var h4 = document.getElementsByTagName('h4')[0],
seconds = 0, minutes = 0, hours = 0,
t;

function add() {
seconds++;
if (seconds >= 60) {
    seconds = 0;
    minutes++;
    if (minutes >= 60) {
        minutes = 0;
        hours++;
    }
}

h4.textContent = (hours ? (hours > 9 ? hours : "0" + hours) : "00") + ":" + (minutes ? (minutes > 9 ? minutes : "0" + minutes) : "00") + ":" + (seconds > 9 ? seconds : "0" + seconds);
}

function timer() {
t = setTimeout(add, 1000);
}
```

And here is the code when I want to stop the timer, I can stop the ball but how to stop the timer?

```
if (ball.position.x <= -fieldWidth/2 && ball.position.x >= fieldWidth/2){

    ballSpeed = 0;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call function`clearTimeout(myVar);`, where `myVar` in your sample is `t`
On w3schools.com have good example http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Comment: thank you for your response, I am trying as you are saying but it's still working, I am using clearTimeout(t); but it's not working.